# Meteor Package Extracting Forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-react, atmosphere.js

Added `std:accounts-ui` to my `./meteor/packages` file and Meteor server restarts. However it never proceeds past

```
Extracting std:accounts-ui@1.1.15...
```

How can we find out what is causing it to be stuck here?

The system is running Meteor 1.4.2.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: How long have you waited?

Comment: @nicovank 2 hours. Not a slow system. Intel 6-cores 4.4 GHz, SSD, 32 GB DDR4.

Comment: Maybe related to this issue: https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui/issues/67

Comment: @nicovank Deleted `\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.2_3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\bin\7z.exe`. Problem solved!